# Android Battery Profiling. Calculate Battery Cycle

Tags: android, cycle, battery

I am developing a *Battery profiling app* and I am stuck at calculating total **Battery Cycle** for the device. Does anyone have idea about how to get this value either in **API** way or from **adb command** ? Or is there any hack possible ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The power consumption APIs turned into private since Android 4.0.2. There are two ways to implement this. One is using reflection method. Another is to program in source code environment. Here's a reference telling you how to use source code programming.

https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Comment: Can you explain which specific API's to use ?

Comment: @kukroid it's batteryStatsHelper. It is used to calculate the power consumption according to power_profile.xml.